# Карта маршрутизаци шаблон mvc  - вопрос для профи

Tags: php, mvc

Моя цель на данный момент - написать свой фреймворк на подобии yii, но полегче в понимании и удобстве

Вообще я начал его писать еще когда не знал что такое yii и чисто для себя

Но сейчас я хочу сделать удобный инструмент и выложить его в паблик

Первое что я придумал - это карта маршрутизации

Цель заменить мод ревраит красивой для понимания картой

Ссылки естественно на сайте имеют вид

site.xx/404/

Если в карте нет ссылки то автоматически перебрасывает на 404

Вчера размышляя о том все ли я учел, я вдруг начал сомневаться

Прошу посмотреть карту маршрутизации и сказать хватит ли ее функционала или у разработчика в какой нибудь 1% ситуации ее будет не хватать

Сразу говорю что проверки на число, строку, правильность ввода и т.д. будет реализовываться отдельно, дабы не захломлять карту

Структура любой ссылки

```
site.ru/контроллер/действие/параметр/значение параметра/еще параметр/значение параметра/и т.д.
```

Если контроллера нет то он заменяется автоматом на index, если нет действия то по умолчанию он заменяется на index

Вид карты маршрутизации
ключи это контрллеры, в значениях первое это действие, если его нет то по умолчанию index, остальное с : параметры

```
$routes = array (
            'index' => array('index',':id',':p'),
            '404' => array(),
            'catalog' => array('detail',':x',':y'),
            'catalog' => array('index',':z',':q'),
            'search' => array(':s')
        );
```

По этой карте будут работать следующие ссылки

```
site.ru/
site.ru/index/id/1/p/2
site.ru/index/index/id/1/p/2
site.ru/id/1/p/2
site.ru/id/1
site.ru/p/1
ну и т.д. параметры могут меняться местами, быть и не быть
не заданные контроллеры и действия заменяются на index и потом проверяются по карте
site.ru/404
site.ru/404/index
site.ru/404/index/
site.ru/catalog/
site.ru/catalog/z/1/q/2
site.ru/catalog/index/z/2/q/3
site.ru/catalog/q/5/
site.ru/catalog/detail
site.ru/catalog/detail/y/5
site.ru/catalog/detail/x/3/y/7/
site.ru/search
site.ru/search/index
site.ru/search/s/вася пупкин
site.ru/search/index/s/поисковая фраза
```

Кривые ссылки будет перекидывать на 404

```
site.ru/catalog/detail/y/
site.ru/id/
site.ru/index/x/
```

и т.д.

Допустим на сайте стоит поиск и при вводе отправлчется гет запрос

тогда ссылка сработает коректно
а параметры разберутся в массив параметров

```
site.ru/search/?q=поисковая фраза
```

а так вылетит на 404

```
site.ru/search/поисковая фраза
```

Ваше мнение, все ли я учел в карте?
Будет и интерес к моему фреймворку или не париться а делать под свои нужды и не выкладывать в паблик?

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите [реализацию](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) в Rails. Она достаточно полная, и похожа на Вашу :-)