# Будет ли код тормозить, можно ли его упростить? Мозгошторм для профи

Tags: массивы, php, foreach, mvc

В продолжение [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/221288/). Собственно, это код обработки карты маршрутизации.

Пример карты маршрутизации:

```
$routing_map = array (
    'index' => array(':p',':id'),
    '404' => array(),
    'catalog' => array('detail',':id',':p'),
    'catalog' => array('index',':id',':p'),
    'catalog' => array(':id',':p')
);
```

Писал код неделю, исправлял месяц. Сейчас работой кода доволен.

```
$routes = array(тут параметры из адресной строки разбитые в массив);
```

Вот сам код:

```
class Mapper {

    /**
     * Функция генерации параметров маршрутизации
     * 
     * Находит имя контроллера и имя действия
     * Формирует параметры запроса
     * 
     * @retern array Возвращает массив параметров для роутера
     * 
     */
    public static function get_parameters(array $routing_map, array $routes, $controller_name, $action_name, $action_parameters) {

        $action_exists = false;
        $controller_exists = false;

        $error_exists=true;

        //ищем совпадения в карте маршрутизации по контроллеру и действию и формируем массив параметров
        //foreach ($routing_map as $routing_map_rout) {
            foreach ($routing_map as $pattern_controller => $pattern_filter) {
                if (!empty($routes[0]) && $pattern_controller == $routes[0]) {
                    $controller_name = $routes[0];
                    $controller_exists = true;
                    if($error_exists) {
                        $error_exists=false;
                    }
                    if (!empty($routes[1]) && !empty($pattern_filter[0]) && ($pattern_filter[0] == $routes[1] || ($routes[1] == 'index' && strpos($pattern_filter[0], ':') === 0))) {
                        $action_name = $routes[1];
                        $action_exists = true;

                                array_shift($routes);
                                array_shift($routes);
                                $routes_param=array();
                                $routes_value=array();

                                foreach ($routes as $rout_k => $rout_v) {
                                    if(!$error_exists) {
                                        $error_exists=true;
                                    }
                                    if($rout_k % 2 === 0) {
                                        $routes_param[]=$rout_v;
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        $routes_value[]=$rout_v;
                                    }
                                }

                        foreach ($pattern_filter as $param) {
                            if (strpos($param, ':') === 0) {

                                if (in_array(substr($param, 1), $routes_param)) {
                                    if (array_key_exists(array_search(substr($param, 1), $routes_param), $routes_value)) {
                                        $action_parameters[substr($param, 1)] = $routes_value[array_search(substr($param, 1), $routes_param)];
                                        if($error_exists) {
                                            $error_exists=false;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        //}


        //если действие не найдено ищем совпадения по контроллеру и формируем массив параметров
        //данный код контролирует вывод ошибки если вместо действия идут не существующие параметры
        //так же код контролирует вывод ошибки если действие равно index и идут не существующие параметры
        if ($controller_exists && !$action_exists) {
            $action_exists = true;//index
            if(!empty($routes[1]) && ($routes[1]!='index' || count($routes)>2)) {
                $error_exists=true;
            }
            //foreach ($routing_map as $routing_map_rout) {
                foreach ($routing_map as $pattern_controller => $pattern_filter) {
                    if (!empty($routes[0]) && $pattern_controller == $routes[0]) {
                        if(!empty($routes[1]) && ($routes[1]!='index' || count($routes)>2)) {
                            if($error_exists) {
                                $error_exists=false;
                            }

                                    array_shift($routes);
                                    $routes_param=array();
                                    $routes_value=array();

                                    foreach ($routes as $rout_k => $rout_v) {
                                        if(!$error_exists) {
                                            $error_exists=true;
                                        }
                                        if($rout_k % 2 === 0) {
                                            $routes_param[]=$rout_v;
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            $routes_value[]=$rout_v;
                                        }
                                    }

                            foreach ($pattern_filter as $param) {
                                if (strpos($param, ':') === 0) {

                                    if (in_array(substr($param, 1), $routes_param)) {
                                        if (array_key_exists(array_search(substr($param, 1), $routes_param), $routes_value)) {
                                            $action_parameters[substr($param, 1)] = $routes_value[array_search(substr($param, 1), $routes_param)];
                                            if($error_exists) {
                                                $error_exists=false;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            //}
        }


        //если это главная страница формируем массив параметров
        if (!$controller_exists && !$action_exists) {
            $controller_exists = true;//index
            $action_exists = true;//index
            $error_exists=false;
            //foreach ($routing_map as $routing_map_rout) {
                foreach ($routing_map as $pattern_controller => $pattern_filter) {
                    if ($pattern_controller == 'index') {
                        if (!empty($pattern_filter[0]) && ($pattern_filter[0] == 'index' || strpos($pattern_filter[0], ':') === 0)) {

                                    $routes_param=array();
                                    $routes_value=array();

                                    foreach ($routes as $rout_k => $rout_v) {
                                        if(!$error_exists) {
                                            $error_exists=true;
                                        }
                                        if($rout_k % 2 === 0) {
                                            $routes_param[]=$rout_v;
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            $routes_value[]=$rout_v;
                                        }
                                    }

                            foreach ($pattern_filter as $param) {
                                if (strpos($param, ':') === 0) {

                                    if (in_array(substr($param, 1), $routes_param)) {
                                        if (array_key_exists(array_search(substr($param, 1), $routes_param), $routes_value)) {
                                            $action_parameters[substr($param, 1)] = $routes_value[array_search(substr($param, 1), $routes_param)];
                                            if($error_exists) {
                                                $error_exists=false;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            //}
        }

        if($error_exists) {
            Route::NoFound();
            //$controller_name = '404';
        }

        /*
        print_r(array(
            'controller_name' => $controller_name,
            'action_name' => $action_name,
            'action_parameters' => $action_parameters
                ));
        exit();
        */

        return array(
            'controller_name' => $controller_name,
            'action_name' => $action_name,
            'action_parameters' => $action_parameters
                );
    }

}
```

Работает, но код очень похож на говнокод. Проверял, есть ли что-то лишнее в нём — не нашел. Всё нужно.

Будет ли он работать быстро и не будет ли тормозить систему? Ведь он заменяет mod_rewrite.

Может, как-то можно его упростить? Регулярные выражения не вижу, как применить — всё равно куча массивов получается.

Comment: https://github.com/kohana/core/blob/3.3/master/classes/Kohana/Route.php вам там ссылку на `рельсы` кидали, я подумал что это вам тоже будет интересно. `Говнокод - это еще не значит что он не работает`.

Comment: Кстати у вас хорошо получилось! Смотрите как себя на практике проявит. Будут какие-то сомнения говорите в чем. А так непонятно как на этот вопрос отвечать.