# Как найти желающих дорабатывать код?

Tags: php, mvc

Как я уже раньше писал

[Вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/221288/php-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD-mvc-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8)

[И Вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/221301/php-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%88%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8)

Я пишу MVC фреймворк или нечто похожее на то  и очень похожий на yii по своей структуре

Мне очень бы хотелось чтобы мои труды не пропали зря

Как и где лучше всего разместить исходные коды и примеры работающих сайтов чтобы веб разработчики заинтересовались проектом и могли его усовершенствовать, чтобы проект как бы сам развивался?

т.е. любой желающий мог бы внести свои изменения в проект при этом проект бы не разбился на кучу мелких проектов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

про [github](http://github.com), [codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/), [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/) что-нибудь слышали?

Comment: только про git

Comment: Выкладывайте свой проект на один из перечисленных товарищем сайтов, до этого желательно написать каку-нибудь минимальную хотя бы документацию. Затем попробуйте на некоторых специализированных сайтах пропиариться, как на Российских, так и на буржуйских, ну а потом как повезёт:)